# Spring integration ip without xml

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Can configurations from this page http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html reside in Java code somehow, or they must be in XML files for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Integration only supports XML configuration. Camel gives you the option of configuration in [Java](http://camel.apache.org/java-dsl.html) (as well as other languages).

As you can see [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/amqp/127268-spring-integration-and-java-configuration) though, Spring Integration has this on their radar.